# Are questions about Apple history on-topic or not?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, close-reasons

I posted [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320317/why-was-used-as-the-command-key-on-apple-computers-why-not-the-apple-logo) on Ask Different a few days ago. In this short time, it became very popular and got over 25 upvotes. However, a moderator put it on hold for "being off-topic". I have the highest respect for the specific moderator in this case, but I just wanted to put it to Meta, are questions on Apple history on-topic or is the Ask Different forum just for practical questions about Apple hardware/software?

Comment: Thanks for raising this here so many moderators (elected and non elected moderators) can weigh in and help - I’m that guy that voted to put your question on hold.

Comment: Would you mind if I linked to your question and added an edit to this meta post explaining some of the original reasons why asking about Apple is off topic here? https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2608/why-does-the-faq-say-asking-how-why-apple-does-some-thing-xyz-is-off-topic

Comment: @bmike No problemo! Feel free to edit it as much as you wish.

Comment: @bmike Just read that response you linked to. Seems legit :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, thank you for your involvement and contribution to the site. I hope you find it to be a valuable resource!

With regard to your question, although it wasn't me, I agree with the Moderator's decision here. The question you asked is certainly interesting and a great *discussion* topic, but it's not well-suited for the main Q&A site.

The main Q&A site is designed for questions from users who have a **practical problem they are trying to solve** with their Apple product or service.

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page provides a great summary of what is on topic. And the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page is also helpful.

For questions such as the one you asked, we do have a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) room that allows for more general discussion.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I understand your point.