# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - March 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the sixth edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for March 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   grgarside                  320
2   Allan                      300
3   Nimesh Neema               230
4   bmike                      130
5   patrix                     120
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,720 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-03-02).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema             158
2   grgarside                 94
3   klanomath                 73
4   bmike                     67
5   Allan                     59
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,677
2   Monomeeth                 327
3   Nimesh Neema              290
4   bmike                     198
5   Melvin Jefferson          161
```

A big thank you to all 36 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted at least 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     72
2   Mark                      57
3   patrix                    55
4   dwightk                   51
5   grgarside                 47
```

A big thank you to all 22 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   fsb                      204
2   grgarside                197
3   patrix                   154
4   Scot                      93
5   Melvin Jefferson          78
```

A big thank you to all 37 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   LangLangC                115
2   Glorfindel                98
3   Allan                     71
4   grgarside                 47
5   fsb                       35
```

A big thank you to all 30 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     46
2   grgarside                 24
3   Mark                      23
4   fsb                       20
5   Scot                      13
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   patrix                    9
2   Allan                     8
3   fsb, Mark, grgarside      5
4   Tetsujin, dwightk         3  
5   Glorfindel, Scot, pjc90,
    IconDaemon                2
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                   122
2   grgarside                68
3   Glorfindel               66
4   Scot                     61
5   patrix                   43
```

A big thank you to all 66 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1st. [Why was ⌘ used as the command key on Apple computers, why not the Apple logo? [closed]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320317/168832)<sup>1</sup>

- Posted by: Oliver S.
- Votes: **26**

2nd. [When you charge your MacBook, does it matter which thing you plug in first?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320439/168832)

- Posted by: MikroDel
- Votes: **16**

Equal 3rd. [Block all unknown numbers not in my Contacts from calling and messaging on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320565/168832)

- Posted by: M-Sync
- Votes: **7**

Equal 3rd. [Adding macros to Touch Bar in Terminal.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320453/168832)

- Posted by: Michael Ilie
- Votes: **7**

<sup>1</sup> **Note:** This question was closed as being off-topic. For more information please refer to [Are questions about Apple history on-topic or not?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3215/168832)

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Why was ⌘ used as the command key on Apple computers, why not the Apple logo? [closed]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320318/168832)<sup>1</sup>

   - Answered by: Rafael
   - Votes: **31**
2. [When you charge your MacBook, does it matter which thing you plug in first?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320441/168832)

   - Answered by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **22**
3. [Why was ⌘ used as the command key on Apple computers, why not the Apple logo? [closed]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320330/168832)<sup>1</sup>

   - Answered by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **15**

<sup>1</sup> **Note:** The question this answer relates to was closed for being off-topic. For more information please refer to [Are questions about Apple history on-topic or not?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3215/168832)

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [When you charge your MacBook, does it matter which thing you plug in first?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320439/168832)

   - Posted by: MikroDel
   - Views: **4,055**
2. [Why was ⌘ used as the command key on Apple computers, why not the Apple logo? [closed]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320317/168832)<sup>1</sup>

   - Posted by: Oliver S.
   - Views: **2,114**
3. [Block all unknown numbers not in my Contacts from calling and messaging on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320565/168832)

   - Posted by: M-Sync
   - Views: **1,084**

<sup>1</sup> **Note:** This question was closed as being off-topic. For more information please refer to [Are questions about Apple history on-topic or not?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3215/168832)

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [fsb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/88313/fsb)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [LangLangC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/251859/langlangc)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Oliver S.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/274083/oliver-s)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Rafael](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/165396/rafael)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [MikroDel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/220880/mikrodel)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In March our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 524 flags with an average handling time of 13 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 277 comments
- deleted 293 posts
- closed 198 posts
- edited 242 posts
- created 107 posts
- created 467 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: Only 36 users voted? That seems quite low. Is this data definitely accurate?

Comment: @SkeletonBow Yes, it's accurate, **but** (there's always a 'but') upon checking it again I see it's only counting those users who have voted a minimum of 10 times in the period. I've gone back and added a note to that effect. All the other metrics count *all* users, so I'm guessing the requirement for 10 votes is just an added protection against identifying how users vote. Apologies for not picking that up earlier!

Answer (score 7):

> A big thank you to all 36 users who voted on questions or answers this month!

it would be nice to see that number go up...

Comment: Couldn't agree more! Hopefully, as more people come across this report, they'll be encouraged to get more active. Here's hoping! :)

Comment: Upon checking again I've found that the stats only count those users who have voted a minimum of 10 times in the period. I've gone back and added a note to that effect. All the other metrics count *all* users, so I'm guessing the requirement for 10 votes is just an added protection against identifying how users vote. Apologies for not picking that up earlier!